# How to check the range of array?

Tags: arrays, bash

I need to check if the range of users input (first argument) is between 8 and 16.
What I got is this

```
#!/bin/bash
count=$1
if ! ((${#count[@]} == 8 || ${#count[@]} == 9 || ${#count[@]} == 10 || ${#count[@]} == 11 || ${#count[@]} == 12 || ${#count[@]} == 13 || ${#count[@]} == 14 || ${#count[@]} == 15 || ${#count[@]} == 16));then
echo "Error - not in range [8-16] symbols"
else
echo "good"
fi
```

I use array for that, but it doesn't work. I've tried different syntax with "if statement" but still nothing. Are there any other ways to check the range of the first argument because my way looks stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the length of the argument using `${#1}` and then use the `bash` arithmetic comparison operator `(())`, in you case to check the range of an integer whether it is in between 8 and 16:

```
((count>=8 && count<=16))
```

So your script can be rewritten as:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=${#1}
if ! ((count>=8 && count<=16)); then
    echo "Error - not in range [8-16] symbols"
else
    echo "good"
fi
```

Comment: It gives me only the last result 
check ab
good
check
good
check safsaffa
good

etc.

Comment: Now it gives me "Error - not in range [8-16] symbols" for any number of characters I enter

Comment: @Josh What are you giving as argument?

Comment: > ppw dd
Error - not in range [8-16] symbols
> ppw 123456789
Error - not in range [8-16] symbols
> ppw safsaffgggs
Error - not in range [8-16] symbols

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a regular expression to check the length of the input:

```
if [[ $1 =~ .{8,16} ]]; then
    echo "good"
else
    echo "Error - not in range [8-16] symbols"
fi
```